# Does it matter if the object of List(T) is being passed ByVal or ByRef

Tags: vb.net

In the following example, does it matter if i pass the List(T) object in both functions ByRef or ByVal?

Is this right that as List is a reference type so value will always be changes even if i pass the object ByVal.

Would it be better if i pass the object byRef in function "ListChanged" as list is being updated.

```
Public Class MyClass_

    Public Sub TestMethod()

        Dim List_1 As New List(Of Integer)()
        Dim List_2 As New List(Of Integer)()

        List_1.Add(100)
        List_2.Add(50)

        List_1 = ActualListNotChanged(List_1)  '---101
        List_2 = ListChanged(List_2)        '---50,51

    End Sub


    Private Function ActualListNotChanged(ByVal lst As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Integer)

        Dim nList As New List(Of Integer)()

        For Each item As Integer In lst
            If item <> 50 Then
                nList.Add(101)
            End If
        Next item

        Return nList

    End Function

    Private Function ListChanged(ByVal lst As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Integer)

        lst.Add(51)
        Return lst

    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 6):

In your example, ByVal (the default) is the most appropriate.

Both ByVal and ByRef allow you to modify the list (e.g. add/remove items).
ByRef also allows you to replace the list with a different list, e.g.

```
Dim List1 As New List(Of Int)
List1.Add(1)
ListReplacedByVal(List1)
' List was not replaced.  So the list still contains one item
Debug.Assert(List1.Count = 1) ' Assertion will succeed

ListReplacedByRef(List1)
' List was replaced by an empty list.  
Debug.Assert(List1.Count = 0) ' Assertion will succeed


Private Sub ListReplacedByVal(ByVal lst As List(Of Integer))
    lst = New List(Of Int)
End Sub

Private Sub ListReplacedByRef(ByRef lst As List(Of Integer))
    lst = New List(Of Int)
End Sub
```

In general you should use ByVal.  The object you pass can be modified (in the sense that you can call its methods and property setters to change its state).  But it can't be replaced by a different object.

Comment: ListReplacedByVal makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say best practise would be to pass using ByRef if (and only if) you are changing the list. Not a long answer, but it's short and sweet!